# Node.js and Request - limiting the file size of downloaded file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to download a file with the Request library. It's pretty straightforward:

```
request({
    url: url-to-file
}).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(file));
```

Since the URL is supplied by users (in my case) I would like to limit the maximum file size my application will download - let's say 10MB. I could rely on `content-length` headers like so:

```
request({
    url: url-to-file
}, function (err, res, body) {
    var size = parseInt(res.headers['content-length'], 10);

    if (size > 10485760) {
        // ooops - file size too large
    }
}).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(file));
```

The question is - how reliable is this? I guess this callback will be called *after* the file has been downloaded, right? But than it's too late if someone supplies the URL of file which is 1 GB. My application will first download this 1 GB of a file just to check (in the callback) that this is too big.

I was also thinking about good old Node's `http.get()` method. In this case I would do this:

```
var opts = {
    host: host,
    port: port,
    path: path
};

var file = fs.createWriteStream(fileName),
    fileLength = 0;

http.get(opts, function (res) {
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        fileLength += chunk.length;

        if (fileLength > 10485760) { // ooops - file size too large
            file.end();
            return res.end();
        }

        file.write(chunk);
    }).on('end', function () {
        file.end();
    });
});
```

What approach would you recommend to **limit download max file size** without actually downloading the whole thing and checking it's size after all?

Comment: content-length is optional and frequently unavailable so never rely on it.

Comment: @RahilWazir How can I possibly check with `fs` if the file is not on the disk yet? I want to download it from the Internet and make sure it's not bigger than 10MB.

Comment: The seconds approach looks fine; since you've pretty much answered the question already, it makes more sense to put it on Code Review IMHO.

Comment: I`m not really sure, but isnt there a way to listen on the 'data' or 'pipe' event of the write stream and then access the already written file-size? If so, you could intervine there and cancel the request as soon as there is more than 1mb written.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would actually use both methods you've discussed: check the `content-legnth` header, and watch the data stream to make sure it doesn't exceed your limit.

To do this I'd first make a `HEAD` request to the URL to see if the `content-length` header is available.  If it's larger than your limit, you can stop right there.  If it doesn't exist or it's smaller than your limit, make the actual `GET` request.  Since a `HEAD` request will only return the headers and no actual content, this will help weed out large files with valid `content-length`s quickly.

Next, make the actual `GET` request and watch your incoming data size to make sure that it doesn't exceed your limit (this can be done with the request module; see below).  You'll want to do this regardless of if the `HEAD` request found a `content-length` header, as a sanity check (the server could be lying about the `content-length`).

Something like this:

```
var maxSize = 10485760;

request({
    url: url,
    method: "HEAD"
}, function(err, headRes) {
    var size = headRes.headers['content-length'];
    if (size > maxSize) {
        console.log('Resource size exceeds limit (' + size + ')');
    } else {
        var file = fs.createWriteStream(filename),
            size = 0;

        var res = request({ url: url });

        res.on('data', function(data) {
            size += data.length;

            if (size > maxSize) {
                console.log('Resource stream exceeded limit (' + size + ')');

                res.abort(); // Abort the response (close and cleanup the stream)
                fs.unlink(filename); // Delete the file we were downloading the data to
            }
        }).pipe(file);
    }
});
```

The trick to watching the incoming data size using the request module is to bind to the `data` event on the response (like you were thinking about doing using the `http` module) before you start piping it to your file stream.  If the data size exceeds your maximum file size, call the response's `abort()` method.

Comment: Shouldn't there be `res.unpipe(file)` for safety's sake? Or does abort unpipe automatically?

Comment: @herby `abort()` will close the socket and ignore any remaining incoming data. It should be safe to just call `abort()` and be done with it since closing the stream should be enough. That being said, I looked around in the `abort()` code a bit and I didn't see anything that explicitly unpipes a piped stream, so it certainly wouldn't hurt to call `res.unpipe(file)` there too.

Comment: One problem I see with this is that the `data` handler will start reading the stream, ignoring backpressure, whereas only piping will apply backpressure.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. I use now **fetch** to limit download size.

```
const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',t
    size: 5000000, // maximum response body size in bytes, 5000000 = 5MB 
}).catch(e => { throw e })
```